# Dynamic Datagrid Columns based on collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, window

I am having a wrapper for example.

```
public class Student{
       public string Name{get;set}
       public int IDNumber{get;set;}
       public ObservableCollection<SubjectWrapper> Subjects{get;set;}

}
public class SubjectWrapper{
       public string SubjectName{get;set;}
       public bool IsSubjectSelected{get;set;}
}
```

How can I bind this to Datagrid effectively.There could be any number of subject.All students will have all subject column against there name. Please see the following image.Also I want to follow MVVM pattern(less code behind).

[image: UI Mock up]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

XAML

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var student = new Student(){ Name = "Ebin"};
            student.Subjects.Add(new SubjectWrapper() { SubjectName="subject1",IsSubjectSelected=true });
            student.Subjects.Add(new SubjectWrapper(){ SubjectName = "subject2", IsSubjectSelected = false});

            var student2 = new Student() { Name = "Ravi" };
            student2.Subjects.Add(new SubjectWrapper() { SubjectName = "subject1", IsSubjectSelected = false });
            student2.Subjects.Add(new SubjectWrapper() { SubjectName = "subject2", IsSubjectSelected = true });


            var list = new List<Student>();
            list.Add(student);
            list.Add(student2);

//Name column adding
            maingrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn(){ Header = "name", Binding = new Binding("Name")});

//Subject columns added dynamically
            for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Subjects.Count(); i++) {

                var col = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
                col.Header = list[0].Subjects[i].SubjectName;
                col.Binding = new Binding("Subjects[" + i.ToString() + "].IsSubjectSelected");
                maingrid.Columns.Add(col);
            }

            maingrid.ItemsSource = list;


        }
    }



    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int IDNumber { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<SubjectWrapper> Subjects { get; set; }

        public Student()
        {
            Subjects = new ObservableCollection<WpfApplication1.SubjectWrapper>();

        }
    }
    public class SubjectWrapper {
        public string SubjectName { get; set; }
        public bool IsSubjectSelected { get; set; }
    }
```